Optimal sequence analyses and hypothesis testing
I am working with data in R using the TraMineR package. I am fairly new to this type of analysis, so please bear with me.
I have a list of unique states (Ex: "NN",  "s2s",  "allop", "beak touch") that occurred within a dyad over time (Tx). I can use this data to determine when each state was initiated and how long dyads remained in this state.
Here is an example data frame:
ex <- cbind.data.frame(dyad = c("BBB-GOO", "BBB-OOP", "BBB-PBB", "BBB-POP", "BBB-PPO", "BBP-GOO", "BBP-OBB", "BBP-OGO", "BBP-OPP", "BOB-POO"),
                 sex = c("male-male", "female-male", "female-male", "female-male", "male-male","male-male","male-male","male-male","male-male","male-male"),
                 T1 = c("NN",  "NN",  "NN",  "NN",  "s2s",  "NN",  "NN",  "NN",  "NN",  "NN"),
                 T2 = c("NN",  "NN",  "NN",  "NN",  "s2s",  "NN",  "NN",  "NN",  "NN",  "NN"),
                 T3 = c("NN",  "NN",  "s2s",  "NN",  "s2s",  "NN",  "NN",  "NN",  "NN",  "NN"),
                 T4 = c("NN",  "NN",  "s2s",  "s2s",  "s2s",  "NN",  "allop",  "NN",  "NN",  "s2s"),
                 T5 = c("NN",  "NN",  "s2s",  "s2s",  "s2s",  "NN",  "allop",  "NN",  "NN",  "s2s"),
                 T6 = c("NN",  "NN",  "s2s",  "s2s",  "s2s",  "NN",  "allop",  "NN",  "NN",  "s2s"),
                 T7 = c("NN",  "NN",  "s2s",  "s2s",  "NN",  "NN",  "allop",  "NN",  "NN",  "s2s"),
                 T8 = c("NN",  "NN",  "s2s",  "s2s",  "NN",  "NN",  "allop",  "NN",  "s2s",  "beak touch"),
                 T9 = c("allop",  "NN",  "s2s",  "s2s",  "NN",  "NN",  "s2s",  "NN",  "s2s",  "beak touch"),
                 T10 = c("allop",  "NN",  "s2s",  "s2s",  "NN",  "NN",  "s2s",  "NN",  "s2s",  "beak touch")
                 )

I used TraMineR to identify cluster patterns across dyads.
Example code below:
# Compute pairwise optimal matching (OM) distances between sequences using substitution costs based on transition rates observed in the data and a 1 indel cost. The resulting distance matrix is stored in the dist.om1 object.
dist.om1 <- seqdist(ex.seq, method = "OM", indel = 1, sm = "TRATE", with.missing = F)

# create clusters from the optimal matching distance matrix using the Ward method
clusterward1 <- cluster::agnes(dist.om1, diss = TRUE, method = "ward")
plot(clusterward1, which.plot = 2) 

# store clusters
cl1.4 <- cutree(clusterward1, k = 4) # four cluster solution
cl1.4fac <- factor(cl1.4, labels = paste("Type", 1:4)) # factor
table(cl1.4fac)

And finally, I have a dataframe with counts of aggression experienced between dyads,
agg <- cbind.data.frame(dyad = c("BBB-GOO", "BBB-OOP", "BBB-PBB", "BBB-POP", "BBB-PPO", "BBP-GOO", "BBP-OBB", "BBP-OGO", "BBP-OPP", "BOB-POO"),
                 sex = c("male-male", "female-male", "female-male", "female-male", "male-male","male-male","male-male","male-male","male-male","male-male"),
                 agg = c(100, 150, 120,110,90,200,180,160,100,80))

Ultimately, I would like to know if cluster membership predicts the frequency of aggression occurring between dyads (aggression is NOT included in the sequence).

Please provide an explicit example showing how your sequences and dyads look out and when event Y occurs. As is, I cannot figure out what you want to do.

Hi, thanks for the response! I edited by question so hopefully my data and question are more clear

From your updated question, I understand that you want to test whether the sequence pattern (cluster membership) followed by a dyad can predict the number of aggressions within the dyad. Cases are here the dyads and the dyad variable is the id label of the dyad.
From the sequence analysis (SA) point of view, when regressing the number of aggressions on the cluster membership of the dyad you must be aware that you ignore the within cluster discrepancy. In other words, by regressing on cluster membership you would consider that all sequences assigned to a same cluster are equivalent. If this assumption is reasonable for you, you can proceed this way.
Of course, the usual regression caution rules apply. Using OLS, for example, the reliability of the significance results would rely on the independence of the dyad observations. For your data, we may wonder whether the number of aggressions in a dyad BBB-GOO can be considered as independent of the number of aggressions in dyad BBB-OOP, i.e., independent of a dyad involving a same individual (here BBB).
